# Where can I find the version of ruby in which a particular function was added?

Tags: ruby

Like the title, `File.symlink` to be exact.

I've looked in ruby-doc.org but haven't found anything.  Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at APIdock you'll notice that they have this information at the top left, under the method name (versions that don't support the method can't be clicked). Examples:

- http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_object
- http://apidock.com/ruby/File/symlink/class

Same for Rails versions btw.

Comment: While APIdock might prove which versions a method exists in, that might not have any relation to what versions it does *not* exist in, i.e. which was the first MRI version the method appeared in, right?

Comment: I guess I was was wrong in my suspicion: I cannot seem to find an example of the case mentioned in the other comment. Please disregard it.

Answer (score 0):

To make up for the lack of changelogs & original lang spec, you could make use of RVM for empirically testing for the minimum version a method exists in. This is not as exact an approach, but it might answer your question, e.g. `ObjectSpace.count_objects`:

```
~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   rbx-1.1.0-20100923 [ i386 ]
   ree-1.8.7-2010.02 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.8.6-p399 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p174 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p302 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p330 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.1-p378 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ i386 ]

~$ rvm exec ruby -e 'puts(ObjectSpace.respond_to?(:count_objects), "")' -v
rubinius 1.1.0 (1.8.7 release 2010-09-23 JI) [i686-apple-darwin9.8.0]
false

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [i686-darwin9.8.0], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02
false

ruby 1.8.6 (2010-02-05 patchlevel 399) [i686-darwin9.8.0]
false

ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9.8.0]
false

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin9.8.0]
false

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin9.8.0]
false

ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
true

ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
true

ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
true

ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
true
```

Comment: That was cool, thanks  `rvm exec ruby -e 'puts(File.respond_to?(:symlink), "")' -v`